# Canceling Butcher's Ruthless Onslaught

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Suppose Butcher uses Ruthless Onslaught and is chasing a Hero.  Is there a way for Butcher to manually cancel the action before reaching the Hero?

I thought I saw a teammate, playing Butcher, cancel the chase, but maybe there was a stun in effect.  A related question, can other Heroes stun Butcher while he is chasing?

Comment: Yes you can cancel the action. I think you just have to press the button again, but I can't confirm it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cancel Ruthless Onslaught by reactivating the ability.
Also the Butcher is unstoppable while charging, so other heroes can't stun him.